# How to delete or drop lines into a dataframe using specific values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, drop

I'm using this code, but when I group to show results, I was expecting that `No entry` and `Out of Business` didn't appear but they do.

```py
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
data2 = data2[(data2['results'] != 'No Entry') | (data2['results'] != 'Out of Business')]
data2.groupby('results').size().sort_values(ascending=False)

results
Pass                  417
Pass w/ Conditions    233
Fail                  192
No Entry               69
Out of Business        55
Not Ready              28
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

simply use the following code to drop certain rows from a DF:

```
df = df.loc[df['results'] != 'No Entry']
df = df.loc[df['results'] != 'Out of Business']
```

The code will work in a way, that the df is going to be selected without the two rows.

I hope, this helps.

Take care